# Starting with a fresh Magento install

Tags: php, magento

I've been customising my copy of Magento 1.5 for about 3-4 years and have pretty much broken all the rules on how you are suppose to customise it. Making it almost impossible to upgrade and have other Magento people work on it.

The best thing for me to do is start with a fresh copy of Magento and follow the rules.

However, I am struggling to find guides on how to bring over:
1) Orders
2) Products
3) Product images
With the important note that I need to keep the order and product IDs all the same.

Anything people can suggest?

Otherwise, the only thing I can think about doing, is compare my copy of Magento to the original and slowly revert the changes back.

Comment: You can start to develop using fresh Magento.If you are able to export the orders, products and customers from your old Magento instance then you can import these to the new Magento instance.Images can be reimported.

Comment: I would suggest getting a standard M1.9 installation and see if you can point it at a copy of your 1.5 database and let it upgrade.  Then, off you go :)